# Joining sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help with these two queries?

Query one:

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime
set @datainicio='2014-03-01'
set @datafim='2014-03-03'
select right([Location Code],4) as Vehicle,MIN(CAST(CAST([date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) +
    CAST([entry time]AS TIME)) as DaeaMin,min([Veihicle Kms]) as KmsMin,MAX(CAST(CAST([date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) +
    CAST([entry time]AS TIME)) as DateMax,max([Veihicle Kms])as KmsMax
where quantity>=0 and [Location code] like 'v%'  and [item no_]='601.0001' and ([date] between @startdate and @enddate)
group by [Location Code]
```

Query two:

```
 SELECT Vehicles.Designation as Vehicle,
 SUM(Locations.DistanceFromLastLocation)/1000 as
 KMS,convert(varchar(10),LocationDate,120) as Date 
 FROM Locations INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Locations.VehicleId = Vehicles.VehicleId
 GROUP BY Vehicles.Designation,LocationDate
```

I want to join these two query by Vehicle and the date in query two must be between the datemin and datemax from the query one.

Help please Thanks.

Comment: You did *what* in MySQL a lot?

Comment: where is `FROM` clause in your first query?

Comment: Could we get some sample starting data and desired results, please?  And we need the missing `FROM` clause/table reference, regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps and is a little easier to understand than the other answers. Note I have included spelling mistakes ;)

```
declare @startdate datetime
declare @enddate datetime

set @datainicio='2014-03-01'
set @datafim='2014-03-03'

SELECT * 
FROM (
    select right([Location Code],4) as Vehicle,MIN(CAST(CAST([date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) +
    CAST([entry time]AS TIME)) as DaeaMin,min([Veihicle Kms]) as KmsMin,MAX(CAST(CAST([date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) +
    CAST([entry time]AS TIME)) as DateMax,max([Veihicle Kms])as KmsMax
    FROM YOURTABLE
    where quantity>=0 and [Location code] like 'v%'  and [item no_]='601.0001' and ([date] between @startdate and @enddate)
    group by [Location Code]
) x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Vehicles.Designation as Vehicle,
     SUM(Locations.DistanceFromLastLocation)/1000 as
     KMS,convert(varchar(10),LocationDate,120) as Date 
     FROM Locations INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Locations.VehicleId = Vehicles.VehicleId
     GROUP BY Vehicles.Designation,LocationDate
) y
ON x.Vehicle = y.Vehicle
AND y.DATE BETWEEN x.DaeaMin AND x.DateMax
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned from clause in first query, I assume for **first query you are fetching data from 'Locations' table.**
Below answer may be useful.

```
;with temp as 
(
    SELECT Vehicles.Designation as Vehicle, 
           sum(Locations.DistanceFromLastLocation)/1000 as KMS,
           convert(varchar(10),Locations.LocationDate,120) as Date 
    FROM Locations 
    INNER JOIN Vehicles 
    ON Locations.VehicleId = Vehicles.VehicleId 
    group by Vehicles.Designation,Locations.LocationDate 
)

select right(Locations.[Location Code],4) as Vehicle,
       MIN(CAST(CAST([Locations.date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST([Locations.entry time]AS TIME))
       as DateaMin,
       min([Locations.Veihicle Kms]) as KmsMin,
       MAX(CAST(CAST([Locations.date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST([Locations.entry time]AS TIME))
       as DateMax,
       max([Locations.Veihicle Kms])as KmsMax 
FROM Locations
Inner Join temp on
temp.Vehicle = right([Locations.Location Code],4)
where Locations.quantity>=0 
and [Locations.Location code] like 'v%' 
and [Locations.item no_]='601.0001' 
and ([Locations.date] between @startdate and @enddate)
and temp.[Date] between 
MIN(CAST(CAST([Locations.date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST([Locations.entry time]AS TIME)) 
and 
MAX(CAST(CAST([Locations.date]AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST([Locations.entry time]AS TIME))
```

Comment: Given that `MAX(..)` and `MIN(..)` are aggregate columns, you'll need a `GROUP BY` - this should be throwing some form of syntax error.  You also don't want to use `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), especially in SQL Server.  This appears to be heading towards a credible first effort, however.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: it's a bit strong to say one should not use `BETWEEN` with date/timstamp types isn't it? Although it's true that you need to know what you're doing (tip: read the documentation), there is no reason to assume it does or does not apply to the data at hand here. Aaron made a valid point in the linked article that some people might misunderstand the operator but simply throwing it away because of that is not the solution.

Comment: @deroby - The problem with `BETWEEN` is that it tends to promote an incorrect perception of ranges for continuous values: that they have a discrete ending value.  For instance, there's no specific "last" instant in time before I posted this comment, there's just "before it was posted".  This applies to every type except explicit integral counts, where `BETWEEN` should be avoided for consistency reasons; thus, my stance is that `BETWEEN` shouldn't be used _at all_ (and you thought I was taking a strong stance before!).  I probably need to write up a blog post for this somewhere...